# ¿Como validar fomulario de componentes hijos desde el padre? Material Design - Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, material-design

Tengo un componente padre, dentro de ella tengo tres componentes hermanos (hijos del padre), he tratado de realizar las validaciones de formulario desde el componente padre usando "FormBuilder" y "Validators" pero no me muestra el subrayado rojo (mat-error).

Este es el código que estoy usando en el componente padre:

```html
<app-nav-header (onChangeEvent)="changeEvent($event)" (onCallMethod)="onActionMethod($event)"></app-nav-header>
<app-datos-generales *ngIf="evento == 0" (onChangeEvent)="changeEvent($event)" (eventClicked)="childEventClicked($event)" [data]="data"></app-datos-generales>
<app-datos-servicio *ngIf="evento == 0" (onChangeEvent)="changeEvent($event)" [data]="data"></app-datos-servicio>
<app-servicios-involucrados *ngIf="evento == 0" (onChangeEvent)="changeEvent($event)" [data]="data"></app-servicios-involucrados>
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { SolicitudService } from "./shared/solicitud.service";
import { EVENTO } from '../../../core/common/constants';

import { ServiciosInvolucradosComponent } from '../../../components/servicios-involucrados/servicios-involucrados.component';
import { DatosGeneralesComponent } from '../../../components/datos-generales/datos-generales.component';

@Component({
selector: 'app-solicitud',
templateUrl: './solicitud.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./solicitud.component.css']
})
export class SolicitudComponent implements OnInit {

@ViewChild(ServiciosInvolucradosComponent) serviciosInvolucradosComponent: ServiciosInvolucradosComponent;
@ViewChild(DatosGeneralesComponent) datosGeneralesComponent: DatosGeneralesComponent;

public evento: EVENTO;
public data: any = {};

constructor(private solicitudService: SolicitudService) { }

ngOnInit() {
 this.data.codServicio = 0;
 this.evento = EVENTO.new;
}

childEventClicked(event: any) {
 this.data = event;
this.serviciosInvolucradosComponent.listaSelectServiciosInvolucrados(this.data.codServicio);
}

changeEvent(evento: any) {
 this.evento = evento.evento;
 //this.clearTitlebar();
 //this.titlebarComponent.data = evento.data;

 switch (this.evento) {
  case EVENTO.list:
   //this.setTitleListar();
   break;
  case EVENTO.new:
   //this.setTitleInsertar();
   break;
  case EVENTO.edit:
   //this.setTitleEditar(evento.data);
   break;
  case EVENTO.view:
   //this.setTitleConsultar(evento.data);
   break;
  default:
   break;
 }
}

public onActionMethod(event: any) {
 let action: number = event.action;
 let valor: number = event.valor;
 switch (action) {
  case 1:
   this.insertarRequerimiento(valor);
   break;
  default:
   break;
 }
}

insertarRequerimiento(value: number) {
 
 let valor : boolean = this.datosGeneralesComponent.formGrupNewRequerimientoSubmit(null);

 alert(valor);
}
}
```

Este es el código del app-nav-header donde está el botón Guardar:

```html
 <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Tipo de Incidencia" (ngModelChange)="onChangeTipoIncidencia($event)" [(ngModel)]="tipIncidenciaDefault">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let item of dataIncidencia" [value]="item.id">
        {{item.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button mat-button (click)="onClickGuardarFormulario()" color="primary">GUARDAR</button>
  <button mat-button color="accent">CANCELAR</button>
```

Este es el código typescript del app-nav-header donde botón Guardar hace un emit donde pasa valores para que se ejecute la función de guardar que se encuentra en otro componente hijo (app-datos-generales):

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav-header',
  templateUrl: './nav-header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav-header.component.css']
})
export class NavHeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() onChangeEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() onCallMethod: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  onClickGuardarFormulario() {
this.onCallMethod.emit({ "action": 1, "valor": 259 });
  }
}
```

Este es el código del app-datos-generales donde está el formulario:

```html
<form [formGroup]="formGrupNewRequerimiento" (ngSubmit)="formGrupNewRequerimientoSubmit(formGrupNewRequerimiento)">
  <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <mat-select placeholder="Gerencia" formControlName="codGerencia">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of dataGerencia" [value]="item.id">
          {{item.name}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
      <mat-error *ngIf="formGrupNewRequerimiento.get('codGerencia').hasError('min')">
        Campo Obligatorio
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>     
</div>
<div class="row">      
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <mat-select placeholder="Servicios" formControlName="codServicio" (ngModelChange)="onChangeServicio($event)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of dataServicio" [value]="item.id">
          {{item.name}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
      <mat-error *ngIf="formGrupNewRequerimiento.get('codServicio').hasError('min')">
        Campo Obligatorio
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input matInput placeholder="Texto Prueba" formControlName="nombrePrueba">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-error *ngIf = "formGrupNewRequerimiento.get('nombrePrueba').hasError('required')">
      {{ obligatorioMsg }}
  </mat-error>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Este es el código typescript del app-datos-generales donde se encuentra la función de guardar :

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { GeneralService } from "../shared/general.service"
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-datos-generales',
  templateUrl: './datos-generales.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datos-generales.component.css']
})
export class DatosGeneralesComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() eventClicked: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Input() data: any;

  public dataCentroCosto: any = [];
  public dataGerencia: any = [];
  public dataServicio: any = [];
  public tipServicioDefault: number;

  public formGrupNewRequerimiento: FormGroup;

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder, private generalService: GeneralService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
this.listaSelectGerencia();
this.listaSelectServicio();

this.setValuesFormBuilder();
  }

  private setValuesFormBuilder() {
this.formGrupNewRequerimiento = this.fb.group({
  codGerencia: [0, Validators.compose([
    Validators.min(1)
  ])],
  codServicio: [0, Validators.compose([
    Validators.min(1)
  ])],
  nombrePrueba: ['', Validators.compose([
    Validators.required
  ])],
});
  }

  public formGrupNewRequerimientoSubmit(event: any): boolean {

if ((this.formGrupNewRequerimiento.invalid)) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
  }

  private listaSelectGerencia(): void {
this.generalService.listaSelectGerencia()
  .subscribe(res => {
    this.dataGerencia = res;
  },
    error => {
      throw error;
    },
    () => {});
  }

  private listaSelectServicio(): void {
this.generalService.listaSelectServicio()
  .subscribe(res => {
    this.dataServicio = res;
  },
    error => {
      throw error;
    },
    () => {});
  }

  onChangeServicio(event: any) {
debugger;
this.data = { "codServicio": event }
this.eventClicked.emit(this.data);
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿Dónde te da el error?

Comment: No muestra error, simplemente no muestra el subrayado rojo ni muestras los mensajes de validación. He revisado el console del browser y no muestra nada.

Comment: ¿Que es lo que contienen los componentes hermanos? Se me vienen a la mente demasiados escenarios... Por favor, se más especifico en cuanto a tu situación. Mostrar tu plantilla HTML puede ayudar. Con más información más puntual seguro las personas se verán más atraidas a responder tu pregunta.

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas, he actualizado la publicación para mas detalles. Sigo haciendo las pruebas pero no consigo que el <mat-error> se pinte cuando le doy click en el botón GUARDAR.

El <mat-error> se muestra solo cuando hago "blur" a los controles.

Comment: conseguiste resolverlo? esto es lo que necesito

Comment: Si creo. No recuerdo exactamente.